# Setting attributes/instance variables and printing in toString()

Tags: java, return

I have to make return the triangles area and perimeter. I have made 2 functions in the main file.
Here is my `toString()` function:

```
public String toString()
   {
      String printPerimeter = "The perimiter is " + perimeter;
      String printArea = "The area is " + area;
      return printPerimeter;
      return printArea;
   }
```

Then I have set the perimeter and area above that code as:

```
private double area;
private double perimeter;
```

My setter functions:

```
public double setPerimiter()
   {
      perimeter = (sideA + sideB + sideC);
      return perimeter;
   }

   public double setArea()
   {
      double s = (sideA+sideB+sideC)/2.0;
      area = Math.sqrt(s*((s-sideA)*(s-sideB)*(s-sideC)));
      return area;
   }
```

I am sure that there is something wrong with the way that I'm returning it. But it keeps saying `Triangle.java:52: error: unreachable statement` to the lines

```
  return printPerimeter;
  return printArea;
```

Any help?

Comment: you can't-do that. The second statement `return printArea;` will never execute. I think you want `return printPerimeter + printArea` for the `toString()` return value.

Comment: Unrelated, but why do the setters take no parameters and return a value? Seem more like getters to me, despite setting of a class variable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only return one statement from a function.

```
public String toString()
  {
  String printPerimeter = "The perimiter is " + perimeter;
  String printArea = "The area is " + area;

  return printPerimeter; <-- This will be returned

  return printArea; <-- Program control will never reach here 
and hence you are getting the error "unreachable code"

 }
```

Similar to two setters, you need to have two getters:

```
public String getPermiter()
{
  String printPerimeter = "The perimiter is " + perimeter;
  return printPerimeter;
  }


public String getArea()
{
  String printArea = "The area is " + area;
  return printArea;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Either concatenate the two strings (see @Aominè comment):

```
return printPerimeter + printArea;
```

or put the two strings in an array and return the array:

```
String[] dimens = new String[2];
dimens[0] = printPerimeter;
dimens[1] = printArea;
return dimens;
```

or split into two methods `toStringPerimeter()` and `toStringArea()`.

Comment: 1+ for the first solution but I wouldn't go as far as creating an array just to store two objects into it. seems unnecessary and a causes overhead. Also if OP were to take that approach `return dimens;` would fail as it's an array of strings rather than a `String`.

Comment: True, I just assumed the OP would change the return type in the method declaration to String[].

Comment: Alright, I see, but even then the definition of _toString_ is that it returns _a string representation of an object_ not an array of strings or any other type.

Comment: @Aominè I agree with you, probably the method would be better called toStringArray() or something similar. I guessed there was a reason the OP needs separate strings for perimeter and area, using an array would provide this flexibility. As would two separate methods. Depends on the OP needs.

Answer (score 2):

As everyone else said, you can only have one return statement. so here is another alternative implementation to combine both outputs to just one

```
   public String toString()
   {
      StringBuilder sbuilder = new StringBuilder("The perimiter is");
      sbuilder.append(perimeter);
      sbuilder.append("\n");
      sbuilder.append("The area is ");
      sbuilder.append(area);
      return sbuilder.toString();
   }
```

Comment: 1+ for a valid solution but, out of curiosity, any specific reason to use a StringBuilder rather than a String? Usually, you'd prefer a `StringBuilder` rather than a `String` when concatenating strings within a loop.

Answer (score 1):

When return invokes it means that it is the end of a method, in other words your 2nd return statement will never happen. In this case, when you are implementing toString method you should return both messages as one String.

```
public String toString() {
    return "The perimiter is " + perimeter + "\nThe area is " + area;
}
```

or you can use StringBuilder

```
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("The perimeter is ").append(perimeter);
    sb.append("\n");
    sb.append("The area is ").append(area);

    return sb.toString();
}
```

If you want to have 2 different objects as a result of some method you need to wrap it in some wrapper, it will allow you to unwrap it later. For example it can be String[] or some collection or even some custom class TwoString which has declared 2 String fields.
Example with List

```
public List<String> getToStrings() {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    result.add("The perimiter is " + perimeter);
    result.add("The area is " + area);

    return result;
}
```

But it will not work as toString(), it is only an example how to return 'more than 1 object'.

Answer (score 0):

You [can only have](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html) 1 `return` statement. Second one will be unreachable.